# C#: How to convert string to date accordingly to the giver format?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 strings: one is date value like "20101127", the second is format "yyyymmdd". How could I extract the date from the value using the given format?

Thanks

Comment: Watch out: the "mm" (lower case "m") are actually the **MINUTES** of a `DateTime` - not the month!! The month would have to be "MM" (capital M !!)

Comment: I'm trying to think of another way of saying "use ParseExact" so that I can get an answer in :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("20101127", "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

`null` will use the current culture, which is somewhat dangerous. You can also supply a specific culture, for example:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("20101127", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact()`.  Note that month is `MM`, not `mm`.

```
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact("20101127", "yyyyMMdd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method.